# How to delete rows of data within a certain category in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several Subjects who came in for three sessions- they performed a task that gave me several reaction times. Here is a mock sample of my data:

```
  Subject Session  Trial  Stim.ACC  Stim.OnsetTime Stim.RT
  1       1        1      1         1              700
  1       1        2      0         2              392
  1       1        3      1         3              322
  1       1        4      1         4              327
  1       1        5      1         5              403
  1       1        6      1         6              388
  1       1        7      1         7              328
  1       1        8      1         8              374
  1       2        1      1         1              700
  1       2        2      0         2              392
  1       2        3      1         3              322
  1       2        4      1         4              327
  1       2        5      1         5              403
  1       2        6      1         6              388
  1       2        7      1         7              328
  1       2        8      1         8              374
```

I am wondering if there is a way to delete entire rows based on session number and subject number. ie. I want to get rid of subject 1's first session, but not their second.

Similarly, I am wondering if it is possible to use a matrix of subjects/sessions I want to delete so I can do it all at once. For example, all at once delete subject1session1, subject10session3, subject12session2, subject4session2, etc.

I most commonly use dplyr and tidyr for data tidying, but am willing to accept any answer.

Answer (score 1):

We group by 'Subject', `filter` the 'Session' that is not equal to the `first` 'Session' to remove all rows that are not the starting 'Session' for each 'Subject'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Subject) %>% 
    filter(Session != first(Session))
```

---

If the OP wanted to remove the first row for each 'Subject'

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(Subject) %>%
    slice(-1)
```

Comment: why bother grouping in the first example? `df1 %>% filter(Session != first(Session))` yields same result

Comment: @Nettle In this case, there is only a single 'Subject', but i think the OP may have more Subjects

Comment: @user10301129  It doesn't matter as we are grouping by 'Subject'

Comment: This is great code and very useful, but the only issue is that I different sessions I need to delete for each subject. So, I can't blanketly delete session 1 for every subject because certain subjects need session 1 deleted, while others need session 3 deleted, etc.

Comment: @akrun I think I may be confused, does grouping by subject allow us to do what I just mentioned?

Comment: @user10301129  Not very clear to me.  Can you update your post with a new example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution to the last paragraph:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  set.seed(1234)

  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(rep(1,16),
                      cbind(rep(1:2,each = 8),
                      cbind(rep(1:8,2)),
                      cbind(sample(c(1,0),16,T),
                      cbind(rep(1:8,2),
                      sample(300:800,16))))))

  names(df) <- c("Subject","Session","Trial","Stim.ACC","Stim.OnsetTime","Stim.RT")
```

...creates this `data.frame`.

```
     Subject Session Trial Stim.ACC Stim.OnsetTime Stim.RT
  1        1       1     1        0              1     399
  2        1       1     2        1              2     730
  3        1       1     3        1              3     498
  4        1       1     4        0              4     376
  5        1       1     5        0              5     468
  6        1       1     6        0              6     482
  7        1       1     7        0              7     511
  8        1       1     8        0              8     392
  9        1       2     1        1              1     624
  10       1       2     2        1              2     752
  11       1       2     3        1              3     660
  12       1       2     4        1              4     732
  13       1       2     5        1              5     766
  14       1       2     6        1              6     395
  15       1       2     7        1              7     530
  16       1       2     8        0              8     487
```

Create a `bad` `data.frame` or vector:

```
 bad <- unite(data.frame(rbind(c(1,1),rbind(c(10,3),rbind(c(12,2),c(4,2))))))

 1  1_1
 2 10_3
 3 12_2
 4  4_2
```

Each pair is a subject and a session. You could make it a vector too.

```
 bad <- c("1_1","10_3","12_2","4_2")
```

Then create a "badcode" column and filter:

```
 df %>%
    unite(col = "badcode",c(Subject,Session),remove = F) %>%
    filter(!(badcode %in% bad[,1]))
```

Create the list of bad subject and session pairs, and then filter by that list using that last line (if it's a vector you don't need to subset with `[,1]`).